# Sparx EA Jscript Information Flows Realized

Tags: enterprise-architect

How do I retrieve a collection of all the Information Flows Realized by a connector of type Dependency using Jscript please?

Comment: http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,38083.msg237223.html#msg237223

Answer (score 1):

First option would be to use the API.

Loop the connectors and check `EA.Connector.ConveyedItems`

But that will be terribly slow for anything but a trivial model.

So the only sane way is to use `EA.Repository.SQLQuery(string SQL)` to get a list of connectorID's and then use `EA.Repository.GetConnectorByID(int ID)` to get the connector objects.

The SQL query you need is something in the nature of

```
select * 
from ((((t_connector c
inner join t_xref x on (x.Client = c.ea_guid
                    and x.Name = 'MOFProps'
                    and x.Type = 'connector property'
                    and x.Behavior = 'abstraction'))
inner join t_connector cf on x.Description like '%' + cf.ea_guid + '%')
inner join t_xref xf on (xf.Client = cf.ea_guid
                    and xf.Name = 'MOFProps'
                    and xf.Type = 'connector property'
                    and xf.Behavior = 'conveyed'))
inner join t_object o on o.ea_guid like xf.Description)
where c.Connector_Type = 'Dependency'
```

Replace `%` with `*` in case you are working on a .eap (MS-Access) file.

I also have an implementation in C#. On class [ConnectorWrapper](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/ConnectorWrapper.cs) there is this operation to get the information flows from the dependency.

```
/// <summary>
/// convenience method to return the information flows that realize this Relationship
/// </summary>
/// <returns>the information flows that realize this Relationship</returns>
public virtual HashSet<UML.InfomationFlows.InformationFlow> getInformationFlows()
{
    HashSet<UML.InfomationFlows.InformationFlow> informationFlows = new HashSet<UML.InfomationFlows.InformationFlow>();
    string sqlGetInformationFlowIDs = @"select x.description
        from (t_connector c
        inner join t_xref x on (x.client = c.ea_guid and x.Name = 'MOFProps'))
        where c.ea_guid = '" + this.guid + "'";
    var queryResult = this.model.SQLQuery(sqlGetInformationFlowIDs);
    var descriptionNode = queryResult.SelectSingleNode(this.model.formatXPath("//description"));
    if (descriptionNode != null)
    {
        foreach (string ifGUID in descriptionNode.InnerText.Split(','))
        {
            var informationFlow = this.model.getRelationByGUID(ifGUID) as UML.InfomationFlows.InformationFlow;
            if (informationFlow != null )
            {
                informationFlows.Add(informationFlow);
            }
        }
    }
    return informationFlows;
}
```

Once you have the [InformationFlow](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/InformationFlow.cs) this code gets the conveyed items

```
public HashSet<UML.Classes.Kernel.Classifier> conveyed 
{
    get 
    {
        if (_conveyed == null)
        {
            string getXrefDescription = @"select x.Description from t_xref x 
                                        where x.Name = 'MOFProps'
                                        and x.Behavior = 'conveyed'
                                        and x.client = '" + this.guid + "'";
            //xrefdescription contains the GUID's of the conveyed elements comma separated
            var xrefDescription = this.model.SQLQuery(getXrefDescription).SelectSingleNode(this.model.formatXPath("//Description"));
            if (xrefDescription != null)
            {
                foreach (string conveyedGUID in xrefDescription.InnerText.Split(','))
                {
                    var conveyedElement = this.model.getElementWrapperByGUID(conveyedGUID) as UML.Classes.Kernel.Classifier;
                    if (conveyedElement != null)
                    {
                        //initialize if needed
                        if (_conveyed == null)
                        {
                            _conveyed = new HashSet<UML.Classes.Kernel.Classifier>();
                        }
                        //add the element
                        _conveyed.Add(conveyedElement);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //nothing found, return empty list.
        if (_conveyed == null)
        {
            _conveyed = new HashSet<UML.Classes.Kernel.Classifier>();
        }
        return _conveyed;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue I have is the EA.Connector.ConveyedItems object is empty for the Dependency even though I have specified, though the EA UI, that the dependency realizes an information flow. I can only get a non-empty EA.Connector.ConveyedItems object on Information Flows defined with Information Items Coveyed.

Comment: Yeah, you have to look deeper. For each conveyed object there is a shadow informationflow that will contain the conveyed item. See that I join t_connector twice? Once for the dependency, then for the informationflow.

Comment: Thanks Geert - finally got it working! Where could I find a specification of the schema model for the database underpinning EA please?

Comment: There is no official specification, but you can reverse engineer the database using EA itself and/or or buy Thomas Kilian's book [Inside Enterprise Architect](https://leanpub.com/InsideEA)